# Edit openapi mustache template to include an additional parameter in method signature

Tags: c#, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to add an additional parameter in a mustache template autogenerated from API JSON.

Code:
I have added an additional parameter for CancellationToken in the method signature as last parameter.

```
{{#returnType}}System.Threading.Tasks.Task<{{{returnType}}}>{{/returnType}}{{^returnType}}System.Threading.Tasks.Task{{/returnType}} {{operationId}}Async ({{#allParams}}{{{dataType}}} {{paramName}}{{^required}}{{#optionalMethodArgument}} = default({{{dataType}}}){{/optionalMethodArgument}}{{/required}}{{#hasMore}}, {{/hasMore}}{{/allParams}}, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```

Problem: This modification works fine and we can generate proper C# scripts, but we have a problem in methods that don't have any inbuilt parameter. Those methods end up being like:

`DoThis(, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken)).`

How do we put a condition for the comma which says - write this comma only when there are one or more inbuilt parameters? Helps appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward in your scenario. Your template adds a comma currently when there are more items left in the list, so if you remove the condition from that comma (because you're *always* going to be adding another item) you don't need to specifically add one before your CancellationToken.

This has the happy side-effect that if you have no parameters in your list, no commas will be generated (because they're only generated *after* each parameter)

```
{{#returnType}}System.Threading.Tasks.Task<{{{returnType}}}>{{/returnType}}{{^returnType}}System.Threading.Tasks.Task{{/returnType}} {{operationId}}Async ({{#allParams}}{{{dataType}}} {{paramName}}{{^required}}{{#optionalMethodArgument}} = default({{{dataType}}}){{/optionalMethodArgument}}{{/required}}, {{/allParams}} CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
```